# Application (Australia.Luis.ai) is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I try to sign in [au.luis.ai](https://au.luis.ai/) with company account. I see below error message. 
I have created a `LUIS.Authoring` key at region `Australia East` in one of my subscriptions, which I (my company account) have `Owner` role to the subscription. 

Strangely, I have no such problem with my personal azure accout, which has `Contributor` role to the same subscription.
Any idea? Thanks.
[image]

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>   AADSTS7000112: Application
>   '602f9eeb-3e38-441a-b807-e49c9a0af321'(Australia.Luis.ai) is
>   disabled.
>  **Request Id:**
>   43553177-d09b-45ae-b2a5-9bfed2201b00
>  **Correlation Id:**
>   4ec8d87b-cfaa-463a-9cbe-9ddaf2506501
>  **Timestamp:**
>   2020-04-02T08:38:53Z
>  **Message:** AADSTS7000112: Application
>   '602f9eeb-3e38-441a-b807-e49c9a0af321'(Australia.Luis.ai) is
>   disabled.
>  **Advanced diagnostics:** Disable
>  If you plan on
>   getting support for an issue, turn this on and try to reproduce the
>   error. This will collect additional information that will help
>   troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Do you get any error on the Dev Console? Also, can you try using the [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c37) and see if you are getting the expected results?

Comment: I'm using lates Chrome Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit). The API is working fine.

Comment: Can you try opening the dev console(Ctrl+Shift+I) on chrome webpage and then try accessing the LUIS portal? Also, can you try and see if you are able to login on https://preview.luis.ai/ ?

Comment: Still the same error with dev console opened. I can login to both [preview.luis.ai](https://preview.luis.ai/) and [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai/home). I only have issue on [au.luis.ai](https://au.luis.ai/home).

Comment: are you still having issues logging in?

Comment: Yes, still have problem. As preview.luis.ai and luis.ai are still working, it is not that critical. I've voted on you comment, as it could be a workaround for this error.